# response write inside global asax

Tags: asp.net

this example dosent work for me ,I tried Response.write but I am getting nothing.
here is the sample 
(is it also  possiable come up a  pop up window tell the error detail")

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      // At this point we have information about the error
      HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

      Exception exception = ctx.Server.GetLastError ();

      string errorInfo = 
         "<br>Offending URL: " + ctx.Request.Url.ToString () +
         "<br>Source: " + exception.Source + 
         "<br>Message: " + exception.Message +
         "<br>Stack trace: " + exception.StackTrace;

      ctx.Response.Write (errorInfo);


      ctx.Server.ClearError ();
    }
```

Comment: If this is in global, then there is no context to write to. How can asp know which of the many users contexts it has that it's supposed to write to? If you want to display the error to the user, move the above to code executed by the user, eg a page, handler, controller, etc

Answer (score 2):

Method signature of an event that is fired when an unhandled exception is encountered within the application in Global.asax is:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // your code...
}
```

Comment: yes u are right but still didnt work untill put   Response.End(); at the end of methon,in that way problem fixed. thank you all